# Light novel, Chinese or Japanese about a low noble/commoner in a school for kids with magic powers

Tags: seirei-gensouki

This novel may involve aspects of rebirth. It is also either a Japanese light novel or a Chinese novel with a small possibility of being a fan-fiction.

The part I remember best about the novel is as follows:

- A young, human boy, either a *commoner*, *lower class noble*, or *noble with weak powers* is attending a school for training students in magic or magical abilities.
- He is looked down upon by the other students in his class. He is the only one in the class who I'd reborn in a different world from his original world.
- The boy uses body strengthening magic/powers. During a training exercise, survival training, I believe, where the students are required to follow a route through a forest that surrounds their city, the entire class is in attendance.
- His classmates include a royal princess and other high ranking nobles. The students make a big deal out of choosing a leader and eventually choose a high noble boy and his compatriots to lead the class.
- The protagonist becomes the baggage handler basically, carrying others' supplies. The high noble boy wants to show off to the princess and other high noble girls, so he and his friends elect to try and take a short cut through the forest. Thereby getting a high score or something and impressing the ladies and teachers.
- As the high noble has a bit of influence over the class, they agree to the shortcut. The exercise was predesigned by the teachers with the children's safety in mind, so, when they used the shortcut they were attacked by goblins and other weak magic creatures or demons.
- At first the students were able to handle it easily. However, the number of creatures continued to rise and the students were tiring and they became trapped on top of a cliff. Of course, the protagonist is fine, even though he is carrying more weight than everyone else, however, everyone else is showing fatigue.
- The students elect to fight the goblins and fended off waves of them, eventually they were pushed to a point of collapse and in the panic one of the high noble boys knocked the princess back and over the cliff.
- The protagonist at this point uses his body strengthening skills/magic to rush to her, jump down toward her falling self, and then throw her back up the cliff while falling down himself. The students were occupied and not many saw the noble boy knock the princess off so he is ignorant or hiding the fact that he did it.
- The princess brings up the fact that he knocked her off and was then saved by the protagonist. The high noble boys hearing this are nervous and say such things as that the protagonist should be honored to have died for the princess.
- The princess is now pissed and takes control of the exercise, citing the reason being the boys are fools. She leads them to finish the exercise while worried of the fate of the protagonist who saved her. He lives, and moves on with his life.

Comment: Maybe: Arifureta Shokugyou de Sekai Saikyou

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, whereas arifuerta involves a class from a world without magic being transported to another world, I'm fairly certain the protagonist is the only who is from another world. If he is, cause I really don't remember. Also, Arifuerta has the protag going to the Abyss with his other world classmates, not a forest with students from the world he is transfered to.

Comment: It might be Tales of Demons and Gods or Forsaken Hero if it's fanfiction.

Comment: Can you describe the rebirth element in the series?

Comment: How is he reborn? Is he a baby or already a teenager ( Man picked up from the gods, death march). Is he even human afterwards.

Comment: He was reborn as an infant or young child (3-5) and is human.

Comment: How did he die or how did he transfer?

Answer (score 4):

Ah. I found it by chance. It's "Seirei Gensouki ~Konna Sekai de Deaeta Kimi ni~"

A summary can be found here:
https://zmunjali.wordpress.com/seirei-gensouki-konna-sekai-de-deaeta-kimi-ni/

And the piece that is summarized in detail can be found between chapters 10 and 11 of Act 1.